# How to uniquely identify static variables in GETSTATIC and PUTSTATIC commands in BasicInterpreter

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to perform some data flow analysis using ASM, but I need to be able to uniquely identify which static variable is being referenced in a `GETSTATIC` or `PUTSTATIC` instruction.

In the JVM bytecode instruction listing, both commands take in two additional bytes which specify offset and length of a static field. However, I did not see anything in the `BasicValue` documentation that provides these two bytes, or something that I could use to identify the static variable.

Is there anything within ASM that could be used to fetch the identifier for a static? Something that can be used within the `MethodVisitor` framework would be ideal, as solutions implementing other parts of ASM would probably be a little kludgy as the system I am working on is already almost fully developed.

Comment: Two additional bytes after `getstatic/putstatic` instruction make an index into the constant pool. The value at this index is [`CONSTANT_Fieldref_info`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.2) structure which identifies the class name, the field name and type of the referenced field - exactly what you are interested in.

Comment: If you are using your own `MethodVisitor` for parsing the bytecode, for each `getstatic/putstatic` bytecode the method `visitFieldInsn` will be called with the name of the class and the name and the signature of the field as the arguments.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help! I ended up checking the type of the `AbstractInsnNode` at a `PUTSTATIC` instruction, and used the `name` and `owner` fields of that object to tag the static field I am interested in.